# HTML5 Video changes colour when overlapping another video in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, video

I have two or more `<video>` elements on a page. I notice that when one video overlaps another, the colour of the other videos on the page change. Please see here for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2juxfjh8/

In the above fiddle I have 4 `<video>` elements, all using the same value for the src attribute. The top-right `<video>` overlaps the top-left `<video>` by 1px and causes the top-left `<video>` to become darker.

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6D1v.png)

In the second row I have another two videos that don't overlap, and their colour is preserved as expected. I have no idea why this is happening. At the moment I can only see this issue in Chrome (I have version 46.0.2490.71 64-bit installed).

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on, and what I might do to stop this happening?

Comment: Chrome 46.0.2490.71 - looks fine for me. Can you provide image with that issue, too?

Comment: Sure @Justinas I've updated the issue with a screenshot

Comment: Fine on Safari 9.0 also...

Comment: @Mick this issue is specifically with Google Chrome

Comment: This seems to be a hardware/software decoding issue with Chrome in OSX as my issue report on the Chromium issue queue has been taken up by a dev there: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=545403